# C# Write to console slowly

Tags: c#

I am making a simple game and I want the text to be outputted in the console word by word. The only method I could find is using the **Thread.Sleep()** function but this only works for each line. How would I make it write word byword instead?

Comment: Maybe by using Split method on any given string

Comment: share the sample code, you have tried

Comment: Can you show the part of your code which writes the text?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337336/how-to-make-text-be-typed-out-in-console-application

Comment: @D-johnAnshani - yes, that's a better duplicate

Answer (score 4):

You can make helper method as following.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public static async Task WriteSlowly(string word, TimeSpan delay = default) 
{       
    if(delay == default) delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    Console.Write(word);
    await Task.Delay(delay);
}
```

then use it like that

```
public class Program {
    public async Task Main() {
        while(true) 
        {
            await WriteSlowly("amazing");
        }
    }
}
```

and whenever you need new line simply use it like that:

```
await WriteSlowly(word + Environment.NewLine);
```

Of course this is the simplest solution with default delay time, but you get the idea hopefully.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I was busy adding real example usage that I forgot about the other one, thank you :)