# How can I make the sentence print out one letter at a time?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make this sentence print out one letter at a time, but I am unsure of how to do it. I did try looking at Thread.Sleep, but it didn't really work out for me.

```
            string Streamer = "Who is your favorite streamer?";

            char[] charSentence3 = Streamer.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charSentence3);

            foreach(char Streamerchar in charSentence3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Streamerchar);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Basically, I just want to make the sentence "Who is your favorite streamer" print out one letter at a time.

Comment: What problem did you experience with the code you provided?

Comment: Thread.sleep(100);
 Console.Write(Streamerchar);

Comment: @AnthonyForloney Sorry, I just wanted to implement something that would make my code be able to print out one letter at a time. I searched for awhile of how I could do this, but I did not get many results or I got python results. I do not have it in my code, but I thought I could receive some help of how I could do this and how to insert it into the code.

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi Would I have to insert the Thread.Sleep(100); before the Console.Write(StreamerChar);? It is not working for me.

Comment: do u want a type writer effect?
look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337336/how-to-make-text-be-typed-out-in-console-application

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track...

```
        string streamer = "Who is your favorite streamer?";
        
        foreach(char streamerchar in streamer)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.Write(streamerchar);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Strings can be enumerated to get their chars

You need to thread.Sleep inside the loop to make it look delayed..

..but that's about it!

Comment: Oooh I see, thank you I was getting confused where to put the Thread.Sleep, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
        string Streamer = "Who is your favorite streamer?";

        foreach  (char c in Streamer)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This is what you looking for