# Running python code in the old windows console host and not windows 11 terminal

Tags: python, console

I'm currently learning python and want to manipulate the console (set sizes and stuff), but it's hard to do so in the new windows terminal.

So is there a way to make your python code (likely as exe) run in the old windows console host and not the new windows 11 terminal?

I have tried making a .bat file to run the file, but it still opens in the terminal.
I have also tried asking ChatGPT, but it doesn't know what I'm talking about.
The python library 'Rich' doesn't work either.

Comment: You're asking the console to do something it was never designed to do.

Comment: @MarkRansom is there any way to make a new window/application that is text based and capable of doing so?

Comment: Unfortunately doing your own console window is a lot of work, Microsoft doesn't give a basis for one.  The one time I tried is documented at [How should I create a custom graphical console/terminal on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9398278/5987)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that it is not possible to do the following. The application/tool used to execute a file (no matter the filetype) is completely up to the executor. Although, if you want to execute a .exe file on windows using the old windows console host, you can do so by opening the new windows terminal > Settings > Default terminal application, and selecting 'Windows Console Host'. (note: this only works for *your* PC)

I hope this can help anyone else wondering whether or not it's possible.