# Printing strings using MFC Edit Control is very slow

Tags: string, mfc, editcontrol

I find that printing strings using MFC Edit Control is very slow, but it's relatively faster when using printf to output strings to the debug console. I'd like to know the fastest way to output strings using MFC Edit Control, along with some example code.

I'm developing a program that reads a binary file and outputs it to the user as a hex string.
When I use printf to output this string to the MFC debug console, it runs within 2 seconds for a 3MB file.
However, when I try to output the same string to an Edit Control, it takes over 20 seconds.
I'm wondering if it's just that outputting large strings to an Edit Control takes longer or if there's a way to output to it as quickly as to the console.

I believe we could create a program like a Text Viewer using MFC, and when opening files to display text to the user, it should be able to quickly show large amounts of text.

Comment: Edit controls aren't designed to work with large amounts of text.

Comment: @MarkRansom
Then, Is there a way to display a large amount of text to the user as quickly as printf in an MFC program?
I believe we could create a program like a Text Viewer using MFC, and when opening files to display text to the user, it should be able to quickly show large amounts of text. So I believe somebody knows it.

Comment: `printf()` is incredibly slow. Displaying text to a user in a window should be *much* faster.

Comment: Are you adding the text line-by-line? This means appending the text to a buffer and then changing the whole text (set the text of the control to that in the buffer). If so try setting the "selection" to the end of the text currently in the control (StartSel=EndSel=TextLen) and "replace" the selection (using the Win32 message or MFC function). Wrapping  lines may be an issue as well.

Comment: I wrote up some guidance on writing a custom window to replace the edit control once.  Unfortunately no code was included.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/9398278/5987

Comment: Show some of the relevant code. That's easier to understand than a lengthy description. Especially the code you describe in _"I try to output the same string to an Edit Control"_ would be interesting.